# Which C++ STL container provides `extract_max()`, `find(element_value)` and `modify(element)` functionality?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to use a C++ STL container to implement [Prim's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim's_algorithm). I need `extract_max`, `find(element)` and `modify(element_value)` functionality, but `std::priority_queue` only provides `extract_max`. Is there some other container that I can use? Obviously I want all of these to be as fast as possible.

Edit: The container should also provide functionality to modify the value of its element.

Comment: IIRC you will have to make your own heap and bookkeeping on it. That gives you `find` in O(N) and `extract_max` in O(log(N)). (Also `insert` in O(log(N))). Use [algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) header to help you.

Comment: @Xarn: Wouldn't `std::set` work fine?

Comment: @MooingDuck I would have to look up how it deals with multiple elements that aren't equal, but aren't smaller than any other. And even then, I would expect it to be massively slower than using `std::make_heap` and `std::pop_heap` (and `std::push_heap` etc) to implement your own max heap.

Comment: @Xarn: `priority_queue` and `make_heap` also fail if there are elements that aren't equal but aren't smaller than any other, so I think that observation doesn't apply here.  It does have less locality, but I'd expect with a pool allocator it wouldn't be significantly slower than a heap.  It's notable that both find by value _and_ extract the max are O(log(n)) whereas the "own max heap" suggestions are complex or O(n) at one task.

Comment: @MooingDuck No they do not fail. Remember that in this class of tasks, your element will look like `struct edge { int cost, int vertex_from, int vertex_to; /*impl*/};` and you want your elements to be sorted by cost, but obviously their equality depends on all three members. Both `make_heap` and `priority_queue` are completely OK with this, because they do not expect their elements to be unique inside them, just that the ordering function is consistent. (IE only one of these can be true `a < b`, `b < a`, for any two given `a` and `b`, but neither has to be)

Comment: @sushilkumar: You'll have to either use `std::multiset` (which is slow) write your own heap functions that keep look-up table to find and modify elements. I've done this before, it's not too bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Push your elements in an `std::set<T, std::greater<T>>`, which is an ordered heap.

- Call [`*set::begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/begin) to get to the max element on O(1) or O(log(n)), depending on how `set::begin()` is implemented.
- Use [`set::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) to perform a search in O(log(n)).
- To modify an element, you must unfortunately remove it from the set and then insert the modified version.  (This also applies to `make_heap` and friends).  There could exist an answer where this is not necessary, but (A) you'd have to be paranoid about what members are used for comparison vs equality, and (B) the difference in speed is very small.  So there is no common container that works that way.
- If the element ordering is not unique in it's ordering, use `std::multiset` instead, which is otherwise identical.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::set<int, std::greater<int>> v { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9 };

    std::cout << "initially, v: ";
    for (auto i : v) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    auto largest = *v.begin();
    v.erase(v.begin());
    std::cout << "largest element: " << largest << '\n';

    std::cout << "after removing the largest element, v: ";
    for (auto i : v) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1e10a2274005fd9)**

Comment: How about using `std::greater` as comparator?

Comment: @bamboon: Hmm, that would simplify the code somewhat wouldn't it?  Good idea